# How to iterate and work on the values of a map whose values are a list of elements using java 8 streams and lambdas

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming

Gist: We are trying to rewrite our old java code with java 8 streams and lambdas wherever possible.

Question:
I have a map whose key is a string and values are list of user defined objects.

```
Map<String, List<Person>> personMap = new HashMap<String, List<Person>>();
personMap.put("A", Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3, person4));
personMap.put("B", Arrays.asList(person5, person6, person7, person8));
```

Here the persons are grouped based on their name's starting character.

I want to find the average age of the persons on the list for every key in the map.

For the same, i have tried many things mentioned in stackoverflow but none is matching with my case or few are syntactically not working.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Can you share any code you have tried?

Comment: personMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, "I am stuck here..."));

Comment: Just want to share this. This is kind of strange, In eclipse when i am typing the below, element. it is somehow treating element as type Object and not giving methods other than the Object type.
personMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, element -> element.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).average().orElse(-1)));

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't specify how (or if) you would like the ages to be stored, so I have it as just a print statement at the moment.  Nevertheless, it's as simple as iterating over each entry in the `Map` and printing the average of each `List` (after mapping the `Person` objects to their age):

```
personMap.forEach((k, v) -> {
    System.out.println("Average age for " + k + ": " + v.stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).average().orElse(-1));
});
```

If you would like to store it within another `Map`, then you can collect it to one pretty easily:

```
personMap.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()
                                                            .stream()
                                                            .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
                                                            .average()
                                                            .orElse(-1)));
```

**Note**: `-1` is returned if no average is present, and this assumes a getter method exists within `Person` called `getAge`, returning an `int`.

Comment: I think this works out but is it advisable to use stream inside stream?

Comment: It's perfectly fine, but there's obviously some stream overhead that will make it less efficient than traditional for-loops.  You won't be able to benefit from parallel streams either unless the inner lists are huge.

Comment: Happy to help; let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Any idea about the below? why it is happening?

In eclipse when i am typing the below, 'element.' it is somehow treating element as type Object and not giving method suggestions other than the Object type.
personMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, element -> element.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Person::getAge).average().orElse(-1)));

Comment: It worked fine for me in Intellij.  Are you using both the latest version of Eclipse and Java?

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen, jdk1.8.0_152. OK. doesn't matter. Thanks.

Comment: I believe there were many inference enhancements in Java 9 that might solve your bug, so I recommend updating.  For now, you can explicitly specify the generic type in `Collectors#toMap`, but it’ll look a bit messy.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like so:

```
// this will get the average over a list
Function<List<Person>, Double> avgFun = (personList) ->
   personList.stream()
      .mapToInt(Person::getAge)
      .average()
      .orElseGet(null);

// this will get the averages over your map
Map<String, Double> result = personMap.entrySet().stream()
   .collect(Collectors.toMap(
      Map.Entry::getKey,
      entry -> avgFun.apply(entry.getValue())
   ));
```

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. This is elegant too.